# Python problems loadtext

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to open and plot *.dat file(s), but when I force Python to execute my dreams ;) it throws back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "panel_plot.py", line 10, in <module>
    x, y = np.loadtxt(file_name, dtype=float, delimiter='\t', unpack=True, skiprows=1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 848, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1.000000  0.001260
```

The part of my programm, responsible for reading the .dat files is:

```
with open ('naca0012.dat') as file_name: x, y = np.loadtxt(file_name, dtype=float, delimiter='\t', unpack=True, skiprows=1)
```

later on the programm writes these coordinates into an array, which I am going to need for plotting the geometry. Thanks for your help!

Best regards
Linus

Comment: You've told np.loadtxt that the data is tab separated - can you double check that it actually is tab separated on the line with the numbers in the error? It looks like it's trying to load "1.000000  0.001260" as a single number, not two tab-separated numbers.

Comment: Hi, 

my .dat file looks like

NACA 0012 AIRFOILS
  1.000000  0.001260
  0.999416  0.001342
  0.997666  0.001587
  0.994753  0.001994
  0.990685  0.002560
  0.985471  0.003280

you can get these files from [airfoils][1]

to Simon Fraser: Yeah, I know, but how can I tell Phyton to use the "left" number as x coordinate and the "right" one as y coordinate?

to jonrsharpe, each x coordinate number is seperated from the other coordinate with a white space


  [1]: http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=n0012-il

Comment: I've checked one of the dat files, it doesn't appear to be tab separated. The default for 'delimiter' is 'any whitespace' so if you remove "delimiter='\t'," from your code it should work.

Comment: thank you for your great help and time!